# Native element have zero size

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet

In code i have reference to my DOM element using ViewChild.
But if i try to check this element in ngAfterViewInit hook, i see that my element has offsetHeight and offsetWidth is zero.(Sometimes all is ok)
I think that is because the element that i created has not been rendered in the Dom yet?
Is there any solution to this?
I'm using Ionic 4.

```
HTML:

<div id="map" #map [style.height.px] = "'300'" [style.width.px]="'100'"></div>
```

```
TS:

...
map: any;
@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadMap();
}

loadMap() {  
    //usually return 0  
    console.log('height:' + this.mapElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight); 
    console.log('width:' + this.mapElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth);

    this.map = DG.map(this.mapElement.nativeElement);
}
...
```

I expect get height 300 and width 100.

Comment: Can you add fiddle/snippet which reproduces your issue? So far as your [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvlwbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) given there is no issue.

Comment: @Mukyuu Yes, code in snippet not reproduce error ( Is that maybe because my app is more heavy, or problem with ionic 4 (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad code, but it works

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    }, 0);    
}
```